# Arithmetic on char* pointers in c that gives an error

Tags: c, pointers

I'd like to add and subtract pointers, e.g.

```
memcpy(sndb + ptr - recb, argv[3], strlen(argv[3]));
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this:

```
error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')
```

Basically, `ptr - recb` is the offset in `sndb` buffer, so I don't quite get what is the correct way of putting it?

Comment: I guess I've just solved it putting in parentheses: `memcpy(sndb + (ptr - recb), argv[3], strlen(argv[3]));`

Comment: the posted line of code will fail to copy the terminating char '\0' at the end of argv[3].  suggest making the length parameter: 'strlen(argv[3])+1'

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you are trying to add two pointers, `sndb` and `ptr`. Adding two pointers is not allowed in C.
You can add a pointer and a number, e.g. `sndb + 1` would get you to address sndb + sizeof(type of object sndb points to).
You can also subtract pointers in which case you get the distance in bytes between the two pointers. 
With `sndb + (ptr - recb)`, first you subtract the two pointers so you get a number and then you add this number to the `sndb` pointer. This is allowed.